# Finding $\iint_{B} x \,dx\,dy$ where $B$ is the circle $x^2+y^2 -x \leq 0$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

$\displaystyle\iint_{B} x \,dx\,dy$ where $B$ is the circle $x^2+y^2 -x \leq 0$

I am having trouble with this integral.

I already know that $B$ is a circle with center $(1/2,0)$ and radius $1/2$.

I think it would be better to transform in polar coordinates, but what is the variation of $r$ then?

Comment: Why not from $0$ to $1/\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: To use polar coordinates for a disk centred at $(h,k)$ and radius $R$, you would set $x = h + r\cos\theta$ and $y=k + r\sin \theta$, where $0\le r\le R$ and $0\le \theta < 2\pi$ (or equivalent). And then $dx\, dy$ is still $r\, dr\, d\theta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

Your disk can be parametrized as
$$x=\frac 12 +r\cos(t)$$
$$y=r\sin(t)$$
with
$$0\le t\le 2\pi$$
and
$$0\le r\le \frac 12$$

the integral becomes

$$\int_0^{\frac 12}\int_0^{2\pi}(\frac 12+r\cos(t)rdrdt$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{8}$$

because $$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(t)dt=0$$

Comment: why are the limits of integration in $r$ equal to $0$ to $2\pi$?

Comment: @Wybie … because typo. The order is mixed up.  Those are the limits for $t$.  The limits for $r$ are $0$ to $1/2$. $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{1/2} ((1/2)+r\cos(t))~r~\mathrm d r~\mathrm d t=\int_0^{1/2}\int_0^{2\pi} ((1/2)+r\cos(t))~r~\mathrm d t~\mathrm d r$$

Comment: Thanks. Would you happen to know why this procedure in this exercise is incorrect?

$y^2 = -x^2+x \implies$

$y = \pm\sqrt{-x^2+x}\implies$

$\displaystyle\int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12}\int_{-\sqrt{x-x^2}}^{\sqrt{x-x^2}}xdxdy=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12}x-x^2-x+x^2dy=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{-\frac12}^{\frac12}0dy=0$

Answer (score 1):

Recenter the circle with $x-\frac12=u$ and $y=v$. Then, $u^2+v^2\leqslant\frac14=r^2$ and the integral is

$$\begin{align}\iint_{B} x\, dx\,dy&=\iint_{u^2+v^2\le r^2} (u+\frac12)\,du\,dv\\[1ex]&= \frac12 \iint_{u^2+v^2\le r^2}\,du\,dv =\frac12 (\pi r^2) = \frac\pi8\end{align}$$

where the integral on $u$ vanishes due to symmetry and what remains is a plain circle area.